# nginx commands not working after installing and running

Tags: windows, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have installed nginx on Windows 10. After the install if I navigate to http://locahost in a browser I see the homepage for nginx. However when working with a nginx.conf file I am trying to run `nginx -t` but I get the following error:

```
nginx : The term 'nginx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ nginx -t
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nginx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I've tried seeing if there is a Windows Path change I need to do, but have not come across anything else that says that needs to be done. I have tried running this command as an Administrator or non root user but still am getting the same message. Any advice would be appreciated.